# PHP error log problem 'Unable to load dynamic library'

Tags: php, apache, cpanel, error-log

My PHP error logs are filling up extremely rapidly with the following line:

> [28-Apr-2011 13:03:00] PHP Warning: 
>   PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic
>   library
>   '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/'
>   - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/:
>   cannot read file data: Is a directory
>   in Unknown on line 0

I've googled the issue and found several results, but all involving something after the last / where this error appears to be something to do with the path itself.

The site(s) are running on cPanel/WHM on CentOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to check your `php.ini`. One of the entries there does not specify a correct filename, but probably something like this:

```
extension = .

; or the raw pathname as shown in your error.log
extension = /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20060613/
```

That's why the error says `Is a directory`.

The `in Unknown on line 0` refers to your `php.ini` (it does not have a __FILE__ or __LINE__ number, so leads to that mysterious location hint.)